# Excel Array Functionality for Cross Check

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, cross-reference

I have 2 columns in my Excel File. First column is called Planned Q and has values separated by Comma. The second column is called Current Q and it has only one value.

As per below screen, I want to check if any of A2 value is in B2 value it should find/call a MATCH otherwise it is Mis-Match. How can I perform this task?

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SEARCH:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,A2)),"Match","Mis-Match")
```

Comment: Beware, `Q1` will be found in `Q11`. A classic pitfall if one is not carefull =) @DhruvBhatt. If somewhere down the line this could become a problem, one could use `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B2&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")&" ")),"Match","Mis-Match")`.

Comment: @JvdV as the OP is working with Quarters of the year, the only options are `Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4` which is why I did not feel the need for the spaces.

Comment: Ahhh I did not notice it was quarters.

Comment: @JvdV, thanks for your response, too. For now, as there are only 4 quarters initial response from Scott is working fine.